# SQL: LIMIT and OFFSET to find median

Tags: mysql, sql, math

I am trying to find median for odd number of floats. I used the following code for this reason -

```
select a from tab1
limit 1 offset (count(a) div 2) - 1
```

But, this code is giving syntax error. I am using MySQL. Any help/ suggestion towards solving the problem will be highly appreciated.

Comment: what does `select version()` show?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use expressions in the `limit` for MySQL.  You could use a window function:

```
select t.*
from (select tab1.*,
             row_number() over (order by a) as seqnum,
             count(*) over () as cnt
      from tab1
     ) t
where seqnum = (cnt div 2) - 1 ;
```

Note:  This follows the same logic you have in your question, but using window functions instead of `limit`.  There are other ways to calculate the median -- and this isn't strictly speaking the median because it doesn't work for both even and odd numbers of rows.

Comment: Thanks Gordon! Yah! This time, I am focusing on odd number of values. So, I restricted my query to calculate that part only. Another question - To calculate median, do we require sorting the list?